# Looping NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have some table columns in database say: office, hallName and floor. I have some set of values in this table. I need to fetch these values and view it on the `tableview`. So i need to use `NSMutableDictionary` with for loop to get all the values in database. Can someone pls give me some idea for looping this `dictionary`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerating over NSDictionary is most effectively done using

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

}
```

This way you get access to both the key and object in one simple shot.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
NSString *key;
for(key in someDictionary){
     NSLog(@"Key: %@, Value %@", key, [someDictionary objectForKey: key]);
}
```

Comment: His points are too low to accept answers. Upvote his question to award him points perhaps.